TextPainter is predicting Text widget height inconsistently
I have the following code which predicts the height of a Text widget before rendering it.
  double _estimateNodeHeight(String? nodeText, double maxWidth, TextStyle style, double verticalPadding) {
    TextPainter? textPainter = _getTextPainter(nodeText, maxWidth, style);
    if (textPainter == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return textPainter.height + verticalPadding;
  }

  TextPainter? _getTextPainter(String? nodeText, double maxWidth, TextStyle style) {
    if (nodeText == null || nodeText.trim().isEmpty){
      return null;
    }
    return TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: nodeText, style: style),
      maxLines: null,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ellipsis: null,
    )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
  }

const paraTextStyle = 
        TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          height: 1.17,
        );

paraTextStyle is used to render the Text widgets, and sent to _estimateNodeHeight.
I ran this code on the emulator and it predicts the height of Text widget perfectly, but on my device (Pixel 6) it is not completely accurate. Is there something device related that I should be aware of ?
